# updating the dimensions of my cube with React's setState rerenders the whole Threejs Scene

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I am new to React and Three.js but I have somehow managed to build a Pergola builder. My Three js scene is able to dynamically build pergolas according to the width, height and projection inputs. However, what is bugging me off is that whenever I update my dimension variables using the setState function provided, the Three.js scene flickers and resets. I should be able to move around and keep the position of my camera without seeing any visible flicker or reset. Also, I am experience "lag" once I start changing the dimensions multiple times. Said lag dissapears once I refresh the page.

Someone mentioned using useMemo instead of useState but I dont see how that can work out.